# List last commit dates for a large number of files, quickly

Tags: git

I would like to list the **last commit date for a large number of files in a git repository**.

For the sake of concreteness, let us assume that I want to get the last commit dates of all `*.txt` files inside a particular subdirectory. There are tens of thousands of files in the repository in total, and the number of relevant `*.txt` files is in the ballpark of several hundreds. There are already thousands of commits in the repository.

I tried three different approaches.

---

**Solution 1.** [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611486/how-to-get-the-last-commit-date-for-a-bunch-of-files-in-git) gives one answer, based on `git log`. However, if I try to do something like this, it is very slow:

```
find . -name '*.txt' |
    xargs -n1 git log --format=format:%ai -n1 --all -- '{}'
```

In my test case, it took several minutes – far too slow for my purposes.

---

**Solution 2.** Something like this would be *much* faster, less than one second:

```
git log --format=format:%ai --name-only .
```

However, then I would have to write a script that post-processes the output. Moreover, the above command prints out *lots* of information that is never needed: irrelevant files and old commits.

---

**Solution 3.** I also tried something like this, in order to get rid of the irrelevant files:

```
git log --format=format:%ai --name-only `find . -name '*.txt'`
```

However, this turned out to be *slower* than solution 2. (There was a factor 3 difference in the running time.) Moreover, it still prints old commits that are no longer needed.

---

**Question.** Am I missing something? Is there a fast and convenient approach? Preferably something that works not only right now but also in future, when we have a much larger number of commits?

Comment: Have you tried using grep instead of find? I.e. `git log --format=format:%ai --name-only | grep "*\.txt"`

Comment: @deiga: Isn't that precisely "solution 2" above, i.e., get a log of everything and do some post-processing?

Comment: similar: http://serverfault.com/questions/401437/how-to-retrieve-the-last-modification-date-of-all-files-in-a-git-repository

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

In git, each commit references a *tree object* which has pointers to the state of each file (the files being *blob objects*).

So, what you want to do is write a program which starts out with a list of all the files in which you're interested, and begins at the `HEAD` object (SHA1 commit obtained via `git rev-parse HEAD`). It checks to see if any of the "files of interest" are modified in that tree (tree gotten from "tree" attribute of `git cat-file commit [SHA1]`) - note, you'll have to descend to the subtrees for each directory. If they are modified (meaning a different SHA1 hash from the one they had in the "previous" revision), **it removes each such from the interest set** and prints the appropriate information. Then it continues to each parent of the current tree. This continues until the set-of-interest is empty.

If you want the maximal speed, you'll use the git C API. If you don't want *that* much speed, you can use `git cat-file tree [SHA1 hash]` (or, easier, `git ls-tree [SHA1 hash] [files]`), which is going to perform the absolute minimal amount of work to read a particular tree object (it's part of the plumbing layer).

It's questionable how well this will continue to work in the future, but if forward-compat is a bigger issue you can move up a level from `git cat-file` - but as you already discovered, `git log` is comparatively slow as it's part of the porcelain, not the plumbing.

See [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) for a pretty good resource on how git's object model works.

Answer (score 0):

I also think your solution #2 is the fastest, you can find several scripts that use this method to set access times. A way to avoid printing older access times is to use e.g. a hash.

I wrote some script in perl to modify access times, and after some modifications, this is a version which should print what you're after:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $commit = $ARGV[0];

$commit = 'HEAD' unless $commit;

# git a list of access times and files
my @logbook = `git whatchanged --pretty=%ai $commit`;

my %seen;
my $timestamp;
my $filename;
foreach (@logbook) {
    next if /^$/; # skip emtpy lines
    if (/^:/) {
        next unless /.txt$/;
        chomp ($filename = (split /\t/)[1]);
        next if $seen{$filename};
        print "$timestamp $filename\n";
        $seen{$filename} = 1;
    } else {
        chomp ($timestamp = $_);
    }
}
```

I used `git whatchanged` instead of `git log` to have a convenient format with non-time lines beginning with `:`, so I can easily separate the lines with files from the last modification times.

Answer (score 0):

I'm somewhat late to the party here, but [here's a little Bash script](https://gist.github.com/akx/1c99d5d16f7a072b1c505ba63b28e0a2) that uses the invocation in OP's #2, and does the postprocessing in awk. (For my use, I didn't need to see files that had gotten deleted as of the current date, so there's the existence check too.)

```
#!/bin/bash
(
    git ls-files | sed 's/^/+ /'
    git log --format=format:"~ %aI" --name-only .
) | gawk '
/^~/ {date=$2;}
/^+/ {extant[$2] = 1;}
/^[^~+]/ {dates[$1] = date;}
END { for (file in dates) if(extant[file]) print(dates[file], file); }
' | sort
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Powershell function

```
function Get-GitRevisionDates($Path='.', $Ext='.md')
{
    [array] $log = git --no-pager log --format=format:%ai --name-only $Path

    $date_re = "^\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d .\d{4}$"
    [array] $dates = $log | Select-String $date_re | select LineNumber, Line

    $files = $log -notmatch "^$date_re$" | ? { $_.EndsWith($Ext) } | sort -unique

    $res = @()
    foreach ($file in $files) {
        $iFile = $log.IndexOf($file) + 1
        $fDate = $dates | ? LineNumber -lt $iFile | select -Last 1
        $res += [PSCustomObject]@{ File = $file; Date = $fDate.Line }
    }

    $res | sort Date -Desc
}
```