# Top level last commit date in git?

Tags: git

I have a repo I just checked out. It's basically a group of folders where each folder is an example illustrating a technique developing on a specific platform.

However, some of the samples are wildly out of date.

Given a location in a repo is there a way to show the last commit date for each item (file or folder) in the location? So if I have repo foo containing folders bar and bar2 I want to see the last commit date for bar and bar2 taking into account everything under them, but I don't want to list everything under them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the last commit date for a bunch of files in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611486/how-to-get-the-last-commit-date-for-a-bunch-of-files-in-git)

Comment: I suppose it would be a dupe if I thought git log could just give me the top level folder/files that I resided in, but I'm not sure I'm aware of a way. The answer in what you're marking as a dupe does a file filter, which is not what I want. I'd accept an answer using git log that does what I want though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get list of files/directories in particular location using `find` and then run `git log -n1` on each of the items. Something like this will print out last commit's hash and date for each file/directory in ./foo:

```
find ./foo -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -t -n 1 -0 git log -n 1 --pretty=tformat:"%h %ci" | cat
```