# Get last modification dates of files in directory in git

Tags: java, git, gradle, groovy, grgit

I have a folder full of files and I want to get the timestamps of last git update for each of those files.

I'd like to get those in a Gradle task.

I tried the following with GrGit:

```
def git = org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit.open dir:project.rootDir

task showGit() {
    doFirst {
        file( "$project.rootDir/src/main/java/some/folder" ).listFiles().each{ f ->
            git.log( includes:[ 'HEAD' ], paths:[ f.name ] ).each{
                println "$f.name -> Author: $it.author.name - Date: ${it.date.format( 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm' )}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but it prints nothing.

If I ommit the `paths` like so:

```
task showGit() {
    doFirst {
         git.log( includes:[ 'HEAD' ] ).each{
           println "Author: $it.author.name - Date: ${it.date.format( 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm' )}"
        }
    }
}
```

it prints all commit infos for the whole dir.

How to get the timestamps for each file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was fairly easy.

Inspired by [How to get the last commit date for a bunch of files in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611486/how-to-get-the-last-commit-date-for-a-bunch-of-files-in-git) I put together my own GrGit task:

```
def git = org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit.open dir:project.rootDir

task lastGitUpdated() {
    doFirst {
        int base = project.rootDir.toURI().toString().size()

        def dates = file( "$project.rootDir/src/main/java/some/dir" ).listFiles().collect{
            git.log( includes:[ 'HEAD' ], paths:[ it.toURI().toString().substring( base ) ], maxCommits:1 )[ 0 ].date
        }
    }
}
```

and it works like a charm!

The only thing which is slightly dissappointing is, that the tasks on a dir with ~150 files takes ~2 mins to complete...

Comment: You've written a script for Commit Date. OP asked for File Modification Date.

Comment: I'm the OP here